# Align right custom currency datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, format, currency

I want a datagridview column that has a specific currency format:

User input: 213

Output: vnt. 213

Desired output: 213 vnt.

Current code:

```
            var vntformat = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
            vntformat.CurrencySymbol = "vnt. ";
            advancedDataGridView1.Columns[21].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = vntformat;
            advancedDataGridView1.Columns[21].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c0";
```

How to align the currency symbol to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `CurrencyPositivePattern` to either 3 or 1 depending on how you want to handle the space

`vntformat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 1;`

documented here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern?view=net-5.0

You may also need to specify how you want it to show negative amounts using `CurrencyNegativePattern`. There's plenty of options for that shown here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern?view=net-5.0